# Creating Portal Users in SoftLayer using REST API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to make REST API call to create an account on the SoftLayer platform. However, it keeps returning the following message even I have provided value for email:

> {"error":"Missing email address.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

I am trying to execute the following method:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/createObject

I am using curl to setup the POST REST call like the following:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @User-Account-Create.json https://<USER>:<API_KEY>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/createObject
```

The content of User-account-Create.json is the following:

```
{
"parameters" : [
    {
            "email": "user@server.com",
            "address1": "address1",
            "city": "Toronto",
            "companyName": "Company",
            "country": "CA",
            "firstName": "Dickson",
            "lastName": "Fu",
            "secondaryLoginManagementFlag": true,
            "managedByOpenIdConnectFlag": true,
            "openIdConnectUserName" : "user@server.com",
            "permissionSystemVersion": 0,
            "timezoneId": 8,
            "username" : "user@server.com",
            "userStatusId": 0
    }
]
```

}

BTW, I can't find references to values that can be set on "permrissionSystemVersion", "timezoneId" and "userStatusId" attributes. If anyone can point me to them, it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### To get timezone identifiers:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://<USER>:<API_KEY>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Locale_Timezone/getAllObjects
```

### To get user status identifiers:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://<USER>:<API_KEY>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer_Status/getAllObjects
```

---

Regarding to: **permissionSystemVersion**, it's not necessary to send this property, it will be automaticaly filled with value: 2

If you would like to add permissions to the user, you need to use the following method:

- [SoftLayer_User_Customer::addBulkPortalPermission](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/addBulkPortalPermission)

This is an example of template that it's working fine:

```
{
"parameters" : [
    {
            "email": "user4@server.com",
            "address1": "address1",
            "city": "Toronto",
            "companyName": "Company",
            "country": "CA",
            "firstName": "Dickson",
            "lastName": "Fu",
            "secondaryLoginManagementFlag": true,
            "managedByOpenIdConnectFlag": true,
            "openIdConnectUserName" : "user@server.com",
            "timezoneId": 117,
            "username" : "user4@server.com",
            "userStatusId": 1001
    }
]
}
```

Please try it and let me know your results or if you need further assistance

Comment: With template provided, it is still failing. It still returns:  
{"error":"Missing email address.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

Comment: There is no need to encode before making the request, right??

Comment: yep, it's not necessary to encode, could you submit a ticket please?

Comment: Because I'm not able to reproduce your issue and I need more information about the user that you are using for further investigation

Comment: As you suggested, I will create a ticket for this matter.

Comment: A side question, after executing this create user request successful, will it be able to obtain its API key programmatically?? I am looking for a way to assign permission to this new user with access to a container in ObjectStorage. I believe I need that to obtain it's authentication token in order to make API request to the ObjectStorage's APIs, is that correct??

Comment: In the end, I am trying to manage the container's (of object storage) access permission by using ACL as mentioned here:
(https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/cookbooks/swift_usage/container_acl.html)

Would this newly created user be able to able to access the ObjectStorage's API and regulating by ACL??

Comment: Unfortunately, **it's not possible to set ACL for SL Object Storage**. The SoftLayer accounts has a non-standard ACL behavior. All users on a single account are considered "account owners" and bypass ACL checks for objects on that account, so It's not possible to apply ACL